# Filtering the iNotes Calendar in extlib

Tags: json, calendar, xpages

I need too filter the iNotes calendar control in extlib. When I look in the examples in the extlib application I can see that it is suppose to be connected to a xecalendarJsonLegacyService.

The problem I find with this service is that I can't filter the content based on category or search as with the other view services.

I need to create different calendars/json data based on a search or category in a view.
I have looked at some of the other services but not sure if it is possible to use them instead.

If you have any ideas for how I should create my filter, please respond.

I have attached pictures below showing both the jsonservice and the calendarcontrol.

[image]
[image]

This is what the json data look like in the xsCalendarJsonLegacyService

```
{
    "@timestamp":"20120311T171603",
    "@toplevelentries":"3",
    "viewentry":
    [
  {
      "@unid":"37F0330979C04AF2C12579BE004F5629",
      "@noteid":"32E1A",
      "@position":"1",
      "@read":"true",
      "@siblings":"3",
      "entrydata":
      [
        {
            "@columnnumber":"0",
            "@name":"$134",
            "datetime":
            {
                "0":"20120314T100000"
            }
        },
        {
            "@columnnumber":"1",
            "@name":"$149",
            "number":
            {
                "0":119
            }
        }, etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own REST service (or extension to existing one) in an extension library, but I guess you are looking for something easier.

Comment: I am looking for something that work, if you want reps you need to provide the code

Answer (score 1):

Sorry no code, but maybe (and hopefully) an answer.
Have you looked at the xc:CalendarStoreCustomRestService custom control inside the Xpages Extension Library demo? It looks like they connected the calendar control with a normal JSON view store and that supports search en keys.

Comment: couldn't really find out how to use it, found a custom control but no xpage

Answer (score 1):

I found code you could use but you will have to extend the custom control. I think it is a new component that is not yet included as a xe: component inside the Extension Library.

This is how you use the control:

```
<xc:CalendarStoreCustomRestService id="cc4ccCalendarStoreCustomRestService"
    storeComponentId="notesCalendarStore1"  databaseName="#{sessionScope.databaseName}"
    viewName="($Calendar)">

</xc:CalendarStoreCustomRestService>
```

This is your calendar component, it uses the above storeComponentId.

```
        <xe:calendarView id="calendarView1" jsId="cview1"
            summarize="false"
            type="#{javascript: null == viewScope.calendarType? 'M' : viewScope.calendarType }"
            storeComponentId="notesCalendarStore1">
            <xe:this.loaded><![CDATA[${javascript:if (sessionScope.databaseName == null) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }}]]></xe:this.loaded>
        </xe:calendarView>
```

If you need some more info, this example is included inside the DWA_iNotesRest.xsp.

Answer (score 0):

I googled a long time and the only solution I`ve found is to build your own Rest service

have you managed to filter the Calendar without this?

Comment: No, I have not found a solution yet

Comment: I can add to this that I have tried to use the other restservices and managed to get the json data exactly the same as the calenderjson service, but then I run in to a lot of other javascript problem with dojo